# Celery PeriodicTask won't expire

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to setup a Periodic Task that should expire after some time. I'm using Django 1.5.1, celery 3.0.19 and django-celery 3.0.17 (everything from pip).
This is the excerpt code to create the task:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from djcelery.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule

interval = IntervalSchedule.objects.get(pk=1)  # Added through fixture - 3sec interval
expiration = timezone.now() + timedelta(seconds=10)
task = PeriodicTask(name='fill_%d' % profile.id,
                    task='fill_album',
                    args=[instance.id],
                    interval=interval,
                    expires=expiration) task.save()
```

And I'm running celery with `./manage.py celeryd -B`

The task is being created just fine, and beat is running it every 3 seconds, but after 10 seconds it doesn't expire. At first I thought it was some timezone issue between django and celery, so I let it running for 3 hours (my difference to UTC) but it still wouldn't expire.

During my tests I've actually managed to make it expire once (and the logger kept repeating it was expired, every 3 seconds) but I haven't been able to reproduce it since.

Can anyone shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem and I think celery beat is not honoring the expires.  If you set a breakpoint in your task take a look at the current_task.request object and see if expires has a value (or just print current_task.request from within the task.)

For me, if I manually run the task, current_task.request.expires has a value, but if celery beat schedules it, it is None.

I'm using celery 3.1.11

I filed a bug: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/2283

Answer (score 0):

You can try use `last_run_at` as:

```
task = PeriodicTask(name='fill_%d' % profile.id,
                    task='fill_album',
                    args=[instance.id],
                    interval=interval,
                    expires=expiration,
                    last_run_at=expiration)
task.save()
```

Comment: I just did tht and still got nothing

Comment: Try run celery during 1 day, if tasks would ended after few hours that problem with settings timezone. If I would be right, you should repeat check settings related to timezones.